# ResourceNotFoundException when running on phone but not on tablet

Tags: android, android-resources

When I try to run my app on my Samsung Note II, I get a ResourceNotFoundException for this line

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

However, I don't get this exception when I run it on the emulator or my Samsung Note 10.1.

Both are running Jellybean and my xml files are in folder called `layout-land`, and the XML file is in there. I tried cleaning my project and re-building, but it still doesn't work.

Does anyone have an idea what's wrong?

Let me know if I can provide any more information. Thanks!

```
01-27 22:11:32.975: E/AndroidRuntime(28330): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-27 22:11:32.975: E/AndroidRuntime(28330): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity        ComponentInfo{com.ventusthecorgi.hungrycorgi/com.mypackage.app.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030003
01-27 22:11:32.975: E/AndroidRuntime(28330):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
01-27 22:11:32.975: E/AndroidRuntime(28330):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
01-27 22:11:32.975: E/AndroidRuntime(28330):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
01-27 22:11:32.975: E/AndroidRuntime(28330):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
01-27 22:11:32.975: E/AndroidRuntime(28330):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-27 22:11:32.975: E/AndroidRuntime(28330):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-27 22:11:32.975: E/AndroidRuntime(28330):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
01-27 22:11:32.975: E/AndroidRuntime(28330):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-27 22:11:32.975: E/AndroidRuntime(28330):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-27 22:11:32.975: E/AndroidRuntime(28330):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
01-27 22:11:32.975: E/AndroidRuntime(28330):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
01-27 22:11:32.975: E/AndroidRuntime(28330):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-27 22:11:32.975: E/AndroidRuntime(28330): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030003
01-27 22:11:32.975: E/AndroidRuntime(28330):    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1026)
01-27 22:11:32.975: E/AndroidRuntime(28330):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2131)
01-27 22:11:32.975: E/AndroidRuntime(28330):    at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:865)
01-27 22:11:32.975: E/AndroidRuntime(28330):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
01-27 22:11:32.975: E/AndroidRuntime(28330):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
01-27 22:11:32.975: E/AndroidRuntime(28330):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:307)
01-27 22:11:32.975: E/AndroidRuntime(28330):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1916)
01-27 22:11:32.975: E/AndroidRuntime(28330):    at com.ventusthecorgi.hungrycorgi.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
01-27 22:11:32.975: E/AndroidRuntime(28330):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5191)
01-27 22:11:32.975: E/AndroidRuntime(28330):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
01-27 22:11:32.975: E/AndroidRuntime(28330):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
```

Comment: It helps if you post stack-trace.

Comment: Try putting the XML file in layout as well

Comment: @user370305 I posted it!

Comment: @RaghavSood in the layout?

Comment: Put your `R.layout.activity_main` xml file in `layout` or `layout-port` directory also..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect that you have your problematic layout files *only* in the `layout-land` directory (based on what you wrote in the question). This means that if the device is launched in portrait mode, Android will search for your layout in `layout-port` directory, *then* `layout`, but *not* `layout-land`. I might be wrong but my hunch is that your Samsung Note II starts in portrait mode and thus doesn't see the layout file.

You have to provide a fallback layout resource. Either copy the layout from `layout-land` to `layout-port` and modify it accordingly for portrait mode or just copy it to `layout` directory as a fallback layout.

Comment: even if I specified that the app can only run in landscape mode in the manifest?

Comment: I used `android:screenOrientation="landscape"`. Oh! Do I have to do that for every single activity then?

Comment: oh I did have to. it works now! Thanks for bringing it to my attention! =]

Comment: yes, you have to do it for every `Activity`. well, glad you resolved that. happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, Samsung Galaxy Note II 's default orientation is not in landscape

try putting a set of resource files in /res/layout for those devices which are not fit the specific layout characteristics

Answer (score 1):

The xml files are in layout-land so they are only valid when the app/device is in landscape mode.   Try moving/copying them to just layout and you should be fine.   You may want to put a generic layout in the layout directory and a landscape optimized layout in layout-land (or look at other resource selection criteria).